# How to "Auto-fill" ROWS on Google spreadsheet with data from COLUMNS?

Tags: autocomplete, google-sheets, autofill

I want to drag some data using Auto-fill on one sheet (A) that is a reference to another cell range on a different sheet (B).

```
Sheet A - Data wants to be in a ROW
Sheet B - Data exists currently in a COLUMN
```

If I drag to auto-fill on (A) horizontally, it simply looks up the data horizontally on (B).  How to switch orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the INDEX() formula. In your case:
=INDEX('Sheet A'!$A$2:$A$20,COLUMN()-2)

The -2 indicates the number of column that you are starting to drag autofill, or in other words the number of column that you have putted the first '='.

You can also find information on these two links [link1](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/167222-autofill-formula-down-column-but-change-row-value-letter.html) and [link2](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/84477-Autofill-across-row-from-a-column-(Excel-2000-gt-)).