# Fill formula from other sheet horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula

**Set-up**

I have 2 Google Sheets tabs; `Vertical` and `Horizontal`.

Data in `Vertical` is noted vertically, that is,

```
A1 = X
A2 = Y
A3 = Z
etc.
```

I want the data from `Vertical` horizontally in `Horizontal`, that is

```
A1 = Vertical!A1 = X
B1 = Vertical!A2 = Y
C1 = Vertical!A3 = X
etc.
```

---

**Isssue**

When I set `A1 = Vertical!A1` and drag the field horizontally to fill `B1, C1,...` I get,

```
A1 = Vertical!A1 = X
B1 = Vertical!B1 = empty
C1 = Vertical!C1 = empty
etc.
```

that is, instead of incrementing the number, Sheets increments the letter.

---

**Question**

How do I get Sheets to increment the number instead of the letter?

Simply `copy+paste special -> transpose` doesn't work between 2 sheets, it seems.

Googling around I see a lot of fancy formulas that don't do what they say?

Tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30003770/7326714
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126830
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126844

Answer (score 0):

use this and drag to the right:

```
=INDIRECT("Vertical!A"&COLUMN(A1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using 2 sheets, not one. This doesn't work for me. Or at least, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TRANSPOSE`

```
=TRANSPOSE(vertical!A:A)
```

[image]

Transpose auto fill the others cells so there is no need to drag

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using 2 sheets, not one. This doesn't work for me. Or at least, I can't get it to work.

Comment: @LucSpan by 2 sheets do you mean 2 documents or 2 tabs ?
cause if it is 2 tabs then you just need to replace the `vertical` part of the formula by the name of your source tab and it works the same